# Why is my screen glitching

Tags: 20.04, dell, vga, tv

I have the PC hooked up to show the video and audio from my TV through the VGA port. Sometimes when I'm typing or when a cable moves, the screen starts glitching out and it usually only lasts a few seconds.

I'm using a Dell Optiplex 755 that has a dual boot with Windows 7 Ultimate Edition and Ubuntu 20.04

I'm using 8 GB of RAM

The TV I'm using is a Sceptre X505BV-FHD
It's still usable, but it's really annoying when it happens. Especially during Zooms.

Answer (score 0):

if it happens when you move your cable - it looks like a hardware issue : make sure the cable is correctly attached - try with another cable (maybe a cable issue)

Comment: It isn't that it happens when the VGA cable moves. It happens when the keyboard or mouse cable moves, and even then, it doesn't happen very often. I also already tried using another cable before making this question.